# Memory leak with Mongo Java Connection with POJO cause OOM

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, java-8, pojo

```
String dbURI = "mongodb://mongoji:pass@XXXX:27017,xxxx:27017,xxxx:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs0";
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(dbURI));
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("read");
BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
    data.append("DT", now.getTime());
collection.insert(data);
DBCollection collection2 = db.getCollection("sent");
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> list = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
list.add(new BasicDBObject("email", email));
list.add(new BasicDBObject("email2", email));// multiple

searchQuery.put("$and", list);
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("Yes", "Y")); 
collection2.updateMulti(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Over multiple transactions in the loop, I am seeing some memory eat up with the application which is not getting released and after some time my server getting halt and giving "bash fork Cannot allocate memory" error
I have tried `ulimit`

```
* soft nofile 65535
  * hard nofile 65535
```

but nothing happens , also getting below error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
>       at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1587)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Executors.java:735)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.createTimer(DefaultConnectionPool.java:316)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.(DefaultConnectionPool.java:75)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:351)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.addServer(MultiServerCluster.java:297)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.addNewHosts(MultiServerCluster.java:360)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.ensureServers(MultiServerCluster.java:339)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.handleReplicaSetMemberChanged(MultiServerCluster.java:208)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.onChange(MultiServerCluster.java:158)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster.access$100(MultiServerCluster.java:44)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.MultiServerCluster$DefaultServerStateListener.stateChanged(MultiServerCluster.java:121)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerStateListener.stateChanged(DefaultServer.java:186)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.sendStateChangedEvent(DefaultServerMonitor.java:197)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:164)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: _"Over multiple transactions in the loop,..."_ What are the multiple transactions in the loop you are executing?  There is _no_ loop in the code you had posted. Also, specify the MongoDB and Java Driver versions.

Comment: given code is in loop for inserting into mongodb , and mongodb version is 4.3 , i am using mongodb-driver-3.3.2.jar

Comment: Normally, an application can create a single `MongoClient` object and use it for the application and close at the end. Each `MongoClient`creates a connection pool with the default 100 connections. For more connections, you can configure the `MongoClient` with `MongoClientSettings`. You may want to use newer API, as `new MongoClient()` is deprecated; use `MongoClients.create()`. See [Connect to MongoDB using Java driver 3.12](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/).